# Getting keys from constant object literals

Tags: typescript

Consider the following:

```ts
const foobar = [
  {
    name: 'foo',
    map: { a: {}, }
  },
  {
    name: 'bar',
    map: { b: {}, }
  }
];

type FoobarMapItem = keyof typeof foobar[number]['map']
```

Here, I get `type FoobarMapItem = "a" | "b"`. However, if I add `as const`:

```ts
const foobar = [
  {
    name: 'foo',
    map: { a: {}, }
  },
  {
    name: 'bar',
    map: { b: {}, }
  }
] as const;

type FoobarMapItem = keyof typeof foobar[number]['map']
```

The type is now `type FoobarMapItem = never` ([Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=1&module=6#code/PTCGDsEsFtQGwHQBcDOBYAUJg3pgBHgMYD24KSeAZscQEagBOeAvHgNr4F64ZdfihoAUwBceAOTVi4gDSc%20sAA5iefPqBUBfObzUFaW%20V01HtR1WoHCx4%20g1lGCSlY66EtOvQQAmh3XxN-PECCAF08UBQiUnIAbkxOJABPRSE8ADEaOwBZUEUASSQhaBY8AGshJOJKPGTU6qosxjZwAFdoWiEGULZxJXFQzhAuAD0x8Ynx2pS0zLpGXIKiktZwIQA3LsxAnE4SMgopO1KOXQsCK1EJKQcg525XDW4zIP0-AM4XgnO8S5s7W4KPIuV5EDyuXzPUyfTCheJYXR1WZNBiLQrFUoVKo1JENI7NNodLo9Pp5AZDYCjSbUkbTVIZFFo5alABEhBZeAAPngWaAOdyWbR%20TzvCztkA)).

Why do `readonly` (`const`) objects behave this way?
**Is there a way to still extract these keys from the readonly `foobar[number]['map']`?**

It seems relevant that, if the sub-properties of the `map` property are the same across elements in `foobar`, I no longer get `never` as my type, similar to the first example.

Comment: why do you want to add "as const"? the object was already a const... you declared it as "const foobar" and const is not a type

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro, that's a [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions). It makes the _entire object_ readonly, whereas `const variable = ...` only guarantees the variable won't be reassigned.

Comment: actually i figured it out.  because you made it into a const typescript needs to know more about the types inside the array because it is now immutable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's simplify this a bit:

```
const obj = [
  { a: 'a string' },
  { b: 'b string' }
]

type A = typeof obj[number]
type B = keyof A // 'a' | 'b'
```

The IDE here tells us that `obj` is inferred to be of type:

```
const obj: ({
    a: string;
    b?: undefined;
} | {
    b: string;
    a?: undefined;
})[]
```

So that means an array that has items that have `a` and `b` keys, where one exists and the other is either omitted or set to `undefined`.

Typescript is assuming you meant an array of unknown length full of object that have one key with a value, and one undefined key.

---

At this point, I want to mention this type, which I will get back to in a minute, but keep it in mind.

```
type IAmNever = keyof ({ a: 1 } | { b: 2 }) // never
```

Now how about this object?

```
const objAsConst = [
  { a: 'a string' },
  { b: 'b string' }
] as const
```

Is inferred to be of type:

```
const objAsConst: readonly [{
    readonly a: "a string";
}, {
    readonly b: "b string";
}]
```

Typescript now doesn't have to assume anything, and it locks this down *tight* to be the exact shape of the literal value. It knows you have an array of a *known* length of `2`, where the first object has *only* an `a` property, and the second object has *only* a `b` property. No other keys are allowed to exist, even if they are assigned to `undefined`.

Note that each item no longer has the `a?: undefined` entries. Typescript won't even let you access them to assign `undefined`, because it knows for sure those keys don't exist.

So type `C` here is:

```
type C = {
    readonly a: "a string";
} | {
    readonly b: "b string";
}
```

This is the same as the `IAmNever` situation above.

When you `keyof` a union type, it returns the keys that are in common with all members of that union. In this case there are no keys in common so you get `never`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBtAsAKBjA3jAIYBcMA5ETNAE4CWYA5uTAL4A0Oeh8Z581KPSYtWOALo4cUAJ4AHAKYwAgqhizFIAGZwk6MAFcAtvAU1J2DUoBCagNYKZ2lVOw4A9O4C0P1zlCQsAiIyhAAwuDQali4BMR8VLQMzGycsTx8AkkibBLEEDAB0K5WMGFqVs7BoRGB+sam5tLySgAi9o7OYX6WLTAAkspGAHIKAG5mHU46ABSEpDAAjGwwAD5xvDAATGwAlDCeMGDjZkA)

---

### How do you do it anyway?

You could use [a union to intersection generic type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type) to to merge all union members and then get the keys from that.

That means:

```
type T = UnionToIntersection<{a:1} | {b:2}> // { a: 1, b: 2 }
```

Now you have a type of a single object and getting the keys is easy.

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
  (U extends any ? (k: U)=>void : never) extends ((k: infer I)=>void) ? I : never


const objAsConst = [
  { a: 'a string' },
  { b: 'b string' }
] as const

type C = UnionToIntersection<typeof objAsConst[number]>
type D = keyof C // 'a' | 'b'
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false&ssl=11&ssc=30&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZwCpIJJ2BATgZwgGNhk4AeGAPigF4oBYAKCigAoYoIAPHOAE3xQAhnBBQA-OwDWALlgBKWlQBuSBPyjy4EFXgVdeEAULZs5UBHABmeKBiWr1-A1IxaoOvbma+mRFHxgKCQAIwArAEF8AGFA4PoAbWZWAG8ReQByYSgg3CsAc0yoAF8AGhSodNCs0NzgfLgi0uYAXREhALggv1BIKBi6WEQUdCwcAmJSFHI+iCRrEIjouO7gRLgAVwBbULxWqmY5qAARIekIEAWBqAB6W6hs4oAfR9DMvyA)

I'm not super sure how useful that is though, since you would *not* able to index `objectAsConst` with those keys since typescript can't guarantee that each object supports access by all those keys.

Comment: I'm tracking; this helps. I still need a way to extract the keys like I can without the `const` assertion. Is that possible?

Comment: If `foobar` is `const`  then you already know what the allowed keys are - `'a' | 'b'`

Comment: @ConnorLow See my update

Comment: Looks like we had the same idea for a solution :)